# How to put multiple xml data in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datagridview

Lets say i have multiple xml data like this:

```
<entry>
<url><![CDATA[http://triada.kh.ua/made/?email=abuse@example.com]]></url>
<phish_id>3779980</phish_id>
<phish_detail_url>http://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=3779980</phish_detail_url>
<details>
<detail>
  <ip_address>93.190.41.34</ip_address>
  <cidr_block>93.190.40.0/21</cidr_block>
  <announcing_network>6849</announcing_network>
  <rir>ripencc</rir>
  <detail_time>2016-01-24T01:00:58+00:00</detail_time>
</detail>
</details>
<submission>
<submission_time>2016-01-22T22:42:56+00:00</submission_time>
</submission>
<verification>
<verified>yes</verified>
<verification_time>2016-03-28T14:15:01+00:00</verification_time>
</verification>
<status>
<online>yes</online>
</status>
<target>Internal Revenue Service</target>
</entry>
```

lets say i have multiple of this kind of xml data how do i show the values in a datagridview without overwriting them? I have tried the following code:

```
foreach (XElement result in query)

        {

            string display = result.ToString();

            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader( display));
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


        }
```

But my table gets overwritten and it only displays the last XmlData.Please Help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A datagrid can't have multiple datasources.  If you have multiple data pieces, you need to merge it together and then bind it to the grid.  In your example you can use Dataset.Merge method.

However...  I am not sure exactly how you get your data, but it seems that you don't need to read each XML element and create a dataset out of it.  You should read all the elements at once and then bind it to the grid.